# In Corda, is it necessary to create persistent schemas, objects and tables?

Tags: blockchain, corda

In Corda, is it necessary to create persistent schemas, objects and tables? Can I ignore them if I only need Corda query framework for querying the vault?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can ignore them; you only need the custom schema if you want to query by certain attributes of your state (i.e. `VaultCustomQueryCriteria`: https://docs.corda.net/api-vault-query.html).
There are other reasons why you might want to expose your state in a custom schema: https://docs.corda.net/api-persistence.html.